# How to Store Data once I've encoded Codable Struct to JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I have an array of custom `Plant Objects`.  `Plant` is `Codable`.  I use `JSONEncoder().encode()` to get the `array` encoded in `JSON`, but how do I store this `JSON`, so that it can be saved once the app closes?  I remember with `NSCoder` I could just encode it when the app closes and use the `required convenience init?` to decode it, but i don't see a similar option here.  Here is my Singleton `Class` in which I am trying to save the `[Plant]`

```
import Foundation
public class Singleton{
    static let sInstance = Singleton(mPL: [Plant]())
    var myPlantList: [Plant]

    init(mPL: [Plant]){
        self.myPlantList = mPL
    }

    public func savePlants(){
        let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(myPlantList)
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you like to store array of Plant objects? you can use UserDefaults for the same

Answer (score 1):

Helper extensions..

```
import Foundation

public extension FileManager {
// Returns a URL that points to the document folder of this project.
    static var documentDirectoryURL: URL {
        return try! FileManager.default.url(
            for: .documentDirectory,
            in: .userDomainMask,
            appropriateFor: nil,
            create: false
        )
    }
}
```

Creating a folder that will contain your data file

```
let documentSubdirectoryURL = URL(
    fileURLWithPath: "MyFolder",
    relativeTo: FileManager.documentDirectoryURL
)
try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(
    at: documentSubdirectoryURL,
    withIntermediateDirectories: false
)
```

Saving -

```
do {
     let yourURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "yourFileName", relativeTo: FileManager.documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")).appendingPathExtension("swift")
    ///ENCODE...
    try jsonData.write(to: yourURL)
}
```

Decode -

```
do {
    let yourURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "yourFileName", relativeTo: FileManager.documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")).appendingPathExtension("swift")
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: yourURL)
    let value = try jsonDecoder.decode([Plant].self, from: data)
  }
```

If you want to check the file containing your data, navigate to the url returned by

```
FileManager.documentDirectoryURL
```

Comment: I have checked this in playground, on opening the url returned by `FileManager.documentDirectoryURL` here, I am able to check the file with stored data.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    jsonData.write(to: url)